# SEM: factor analysis and categorical data

Tags: r, categorical-data, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

Lets say I want to run the following model in R/lavaan:

```
F1 =~ V1 + V2 + V3
F2 =~ V4 + V5 + V6
F1 ~~ F2
```

`V1-3` are continuous indicators, `V4-6` are categorical (binary, nominal/not ordinal). Sample size ~1000

An example of the `F2` factor might be trying to capture something about a person's level of fitness, so indicators might be:

Did you ride your bicycle or drive to school today? (Response: Bicycle/car)

Did you go to the gym today? (Response: yes/no)

From what Ive learnt so far, categorical indicators will work if you can safely assume that theres an underlying continuous normal distribution driving the categories.

If you cant meet that assumption, say if `V4-6` are nominal/categorical like the examples above, what would be the recommended approach?

1. Can you introduce some form of logistic regression?
2. And if so, how would that be done using lavaan and how would you interpret the output?
3. Which estimator should be used in a case like this?

Comment: Can you indicate which kinds of true nominal variables could be under influence of a latent factor? I could not think of a latent factor that would "influence" the gender of a person (while vice-versa it could work of course).

Comment: Gender was a bad example. I added more realistic examples to my question

Comment: I guess I'm mostly wondering how logistic regression might work into this. I think thats what the IRT world does with this type of data?

Answer (score 2):

When you ask "Did you go to the gym today?" going to the gym is an outcome with multiple causes, if these causes manage to pass some threshold you went, otherwise you didn't. So I think it's fine to consider this to be a latent variable.

In addition, your model looks like this:

```
F1 =~ V1 + V2 + V3
F2 =~ V4 + V5 + V6
F1 ~~ F2
```

But say that V6 was your nominal variable, and you are not comfortable treating it as an indicator of a latent variable, so instead you regress it on the latent, essentially doing a logistic regression.

```
F1 =~ V1 + V2 + V3
F2 =~ V4 + V5
F1 ~~ F2
V6 ~ F1
```

It turns out that these models are equivalent - they are the same model.

In short, I don't think you need to worry.